# String Index out of Range:java

Tags: java, string

I just want to create a application that could covert natural language into sql queries, in this snippet I want to extract the numbers from a given string.I don't why I am getting this error. Regardless of the length I enter it results with the same error.

```
public void insert(String low) {
    String character = low;
    int l = low.length();
    int j[] = new int[20];
    int m = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k <= 2; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= l; i++) {
            char c = character.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                String str = Character.toString(c);
                j[k] = (j[k] * 10) + Integer.parseInt(str);
                m++;

            } else if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
                if (m > 2) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k <= 2; k++) {
        jTextField2.setText(Integer.toString(j[k]));
    }
}

public void check(String low) {
    int j;
    String[] ins = {"into", "add", "insert"};
    String cc = low;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        String dd = ins[i];
        if (cc.contains(dd)) {
            j = 1;
            insert(cc);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the state of your program according to your debugger when the exception is thrown?

Comment: Can you indent your code properly? 

And what is your input `low` in `insert` function?

Comment: What is the format of a string you are parsing? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 for(int i=0;i<=l;i++)
 {
    char c = character.charAt(i);
    ..........
 }
```

to

```
  for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
 {
    char c = character.charAt(i);
    ..........
 }
```

When you are write `i<=l` , the last iteration of the loop will execute `character.chatAt(l)`, which is not present because indexing starts from 0 and only `0,1,2, .....l-1` characters are available. So executing `character.chatAt(l)` throws IndexOutofBound exception which is self explanatory.

Comment: Thanks,but now the end result is now displayed as 0.Sorry for making you debug the whole thing. And can i know the reason why that change made the code correct

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to extract all the numbers in a string, I'd highly recommend using [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) rather than writing your own code to loop over characters.  How about something like this:

```
public List<Integer> extractNumbers(String line){
    // Construct regex
    Pattern digitsPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher m = digitsPattern.matcher(line);

    // Compile into list
    List<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (m.find()){
        numberList.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));
    }

    return numberList;
}
```

Regular expressions are extremely powerful, mature and elegant - as you see here, you can do this in a couple of fairly simple lines, and if you ever need to change the matching rules you'll have a much simpler job.